# How do I open a new Terminal window ssh'ed to another machine from the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line

From the command line I'd like to open a new Terminal window that is already SSH'ing to a host.

From the command line, I can open a new Terminal window very easily:

```
open -a Terminal
```

or

```
open -a Terminal /path/name
```

(The second one starts the Terminal already "cd"'ed to /path/name.)

However I want the Terminal to open and immediately run "ssh foo" instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this with

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "exec ssh localhost"'
```

Replace 'localhost' with the host name to which you wish to connect. You can include a username if the remote name is different from your local username, this would look like

```
rname@remotey.remote-face.org
\____/\_____/\______________/
 |     |      `- Domain name, you may be able to omit if on the same network as 'remotey'
 |     `- Remote hostname
 `- Specify remote login name followed by '@', can be omitted for same username
```

This suggestion is a variation on the top answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524499/open-terminal-from-shell-and-execute-commands

Use `exec ssh` instead of `ssh` if you want the window to close after logging out. If you use the 'exec ssh' option and your window stays open, then check your Terminal preferences--under "Profiles" > "Shell" > "**When the shell exits:**" is probably set to "Don't close the window"

Comment: That's great!  One small tip: I changed `ssh` to `exec ssh` so that the window disappears when I log out.

Comment: @TomOnTime, That's a good suggestion. Most people will want the window to close after they log out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do it using `open` command.

But, you can do it using a combination of keyboard shortcuts and Terminal profiles.

Define a new profile on your Terminal app (let's call it ssh) and add your ssh command on **Shell** tab under **Run command:**.

Then your can define a shortcut on **System Preferences** - **Keyboard** - **Shorcuts** - **App Shortcuts** like the following:

[image]

Once done, you will have to type the shortcut on your Terminal app and will open a new window with your `ssh` command.

Careful, the Menu Title must have the exact same name as your newly created profile.